# Chaining Mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I try to chain mongoid criterias.

If I fetch a **single** `"$in"` (or `:field.in`, `Model.any_in`) criteria, I get the expected results.

When I combine them like in the examples below, my results are not expected.

- How can I chain them to an AND like query?
  My results should return
- People with BOTH of the IN criterias.

***rSpec example***

```
@person = Fabricate :person, categories: [@c1], services: [@s1]
@person2 = Fabricate :person
get 'person_search', categories: "#{@c1.id}", services: "#{@s1.id}"
expect(assigns(:person)).to include(@person)
expect(assigns(:person)).to_not include(@person2)
```

***.in***

```
query = Person.where(country: "AT")

query = query.in(:category_ids => categories.collect(&:_id)) if categories.present?
query = query.in(:service_ids => services.collect(&:_id)) if services.present?

@people = query.map do |person|
  person
end
```

I also tried

```
query = Person.where(country: "AT")

query = query.where(:category_ids.in => categories.collect(&:_id)) if categories.present?
query = query.where(:service_ids.in => services.collect(&:_id)) if services.present?

@people = query.map do |person|
  person
end
```

and this does not work either:

```
query = Person.where(country: "AT")

query = query.all(:category_ids.in => categories.collect(&:_id)) if categories.present?
query = query.all(:service_ids.in => services.collect(&:_id)) if services.present?

@people = query.map do |person|
  person
end
```

Comment: The two in queries (:category_ids, :service_ids) should be combined with an AND. The results should only be included if both of them contain at least one category_id and one service_id.

Comment: can grab my hair out, maybe found the solution. I had overridden my fabricator definition, so the category was not set proberly. Specs are green. Sorry for that blindness! Thank you mu is too short!